# postgres jsonb sum() per month

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I would like to know how do I sum() the profit per month, the way below, it calculates the total.

```
select 
count(row_data->>'bankMovementAmount') AS "COUNTER",
```

I would like it to sum() by month

```
to_char((row_data->>'installmentBaseDate')::date, 'yyyy-mm') AS "MONTH",
```

```
( SUM( (row_data->>'bankMovementAmount')::float ) FILTER (WHERE row_data->>'bankMovementOperationType' = 'E')
- SUM( (row_data->>'bankMovementAmount')::float ) FILTER (WHERE row_data->>'bankMovementOperationType' = 'S')
) AS "VALUE"
from public.teste
WHERE abbreviation = 'BMO' AND row_data->>'companyName' = 'Nec Plus Ultra Gestão e Tecnologia LTDA' 
group by to_char((row_data->>'installmentBaseDate')::date, 'yyyy-mm') 
ORDER BY to_char((row_data->>'installmentBaseDate')::date, 'yyyy-mm')
```

Currently

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Q6m.png)

Comment: it should work.  It works in pg14. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=541249a63302d6341b34824a9a07bfba). Can you try to do it  on dbfilddle uk?

Comment: so What was the issue make the query not working?

Comment: it was the date ```row_data->>'bankMovementDate')::date``` I had the wrong name. In addition to the adjustments from null to 0 zero, through the coalesce ```coalesce(sum((row_data->>'bankMovementAmount')::float) filter ( where row_data->>'bankMovementOperationType' = 'S' ),0)```